# xmlreader.Create return none

Tags: xmlreader

i am trying to read from xml string But ,

```
 ` XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringXml)`
```

reader is always none. why is reader objest none ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to call the read function.
reader.Read();

Comment: This function not exist in XmlReader object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/794e8dcf-4b09-481c-8742-af46673dd8b3/) for your question. There seems to be no problem and the XmlReader is ready to be utilized.

Actually, if you are open to use .NetFramework 3.5 and higher you could benefit from using Linq To Xml:

```
 XElement x = XElement.Load(new StringReader(s));
```

Comment: c# , has xelement selectednotes method ?

Comment: What do you mean by "selectednotes"? Besides, you are expected to find answers on such kind of questions in msdn, say http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx

Comment: i think this problem is bug.Because have a problem when i wrote xmldocument then xmlreader. But XmlReader reader=XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(stringXml); reader.read(); i hadnt problem when i used the above code :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me in code that had been working for years.  there were two paths for populating the xml string used in creating the xReader.  The first pulled xml from a text parameter.  If the text parameter was empty then it would fetch the string from sql server.  If the text parameter was null, however, then I was getting "none" from the xReader.  This despite the fact that SQL return perfectly formed xml.  If the text parameter was an empty zero-length string, however, then everything worked fine, that is, the fetch to SQL ran, fetch xml and loaded the reader.  It was like the runtime .net engine was running both paths simultaneously and giving me the worst possible outcome, instead of the desired outcome.